# Calling the same View on multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Is is possible to have one View being called on multiple UIViewControllers (also the class of that view), like on php that you include something and that block of code is brought to your "page".

Its just redundant to have a header menu and having to call the same code everytime.

Thanks

Comment: yes it is possible!!!! Use xibs for that purpose!!!!

Comment: You don't need a `xib`. You can create a custom view class and create instances of it wherever you need it.

Comment: I always use xib as it is easier to apply constraints. I dont know why, but I always stryggle in applying constraints programmatically!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xib to create your UIView and load it anywhere in your app.

After you create the xib, make it a iboutlet property in the view controller:

```
 @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *myViewFromNib;
```

and load the xib by:

```
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myView" owner:self options:nil];

  [self.view addSubview:self.myViewFromNib];
```

This is the way I always use, as it will be easier for the autolayout and applying constraints.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.T that was what I looking for